# OpenYouTubeActivity: fullscreen is not working on Android 4.3

Tags: android, video, fullscreen, android-video-player, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm using OpenYouTubeActivity (https://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/) to play videos in my Android app. And everything was ok, until Android 4.3.
On devices upgraded to 4.3 videos are playing, but not fullscreen, as before. Just small sized video in the center of the screen.

My code to start playing video is simple, but working fine before 4.3:

```
Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytv://"+YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID), this, YoutubeActivity.class);
startActivity(lVideoIntent);
```

YoutubeActivity extends OpenYouTubePlayerActivity and does almost nothing new except

```
View vw = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
vw.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

Maybe someone knows what was changed in 4.3 that could cause that issue, and how to workaround it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ОК, I found one workaround myself: just replaced the player jar with official from google (https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)

Now it works as intended on my Nexus with Android 4.3

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.